# Bad JSON request is being sent in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am building an API within Laravel. I have the following code:

```
//time validation has expired
if(strcmp(json_encode("0"), $isUserCodeValid) == 0) 
{
    dd('I am in the code bloack');
    return Response::json([
        'response' => [
            'message' => 'Improper credentials. Request Time span has expired',
            'code' => 510
        ]
    ],400);
}
```

Just to be sure that the comparison is correct and valid, I placed a dd statement inside the if-statement, which works correctly. I hit the dd statement when accessed.

However, when I access the URL (and when the dd statement is removed), I keep getting a **bad request**. The error is

> Unexpected token B

**Update 1**

```
Route::post('createTopic','ApiController@createTopic');
```

Controller Action

```
public function createTopic()
    {
        if(Request::isJson())
        {
            $input = Input::all();


            //check if the usercode is properly encrypted.

            $encUserCode = $input['usercode'];

            $encryption = new Encryption();            

            $usercode = $encryption->decrypt($encUserCode)[0];


            if(!isset($usercode))
            {
                return Response::json([
                    'response' => [
                        'message' => 'Improper credentials. The usercode is not set.',
                        'code' => 52
                    ]
                ],400);
            }

            $isUserCodeValid = $encryption->isValid($encUserCode);

            //time validation has expired
            if(strcmp(json_encode("0"), $isUserCodeValid) == 0) 
            {
                return Response::json([
                    'response' => [
                        'message' => 'Improper credentials. Request Time span has expired',
                        'code' => 980
                    ]
                ]);



            }




            try {

                // trying logging in with the user that was present in the JSON .
                //If the user does not exist then create the user assigning him the default role.

                //first get the user.


                //mission critical actions are done here. removed for stackoverflow.


            }
            catch(Exception $ex)
            {
                return Response::json([
                    'response' => [
                        'message' => 'An error has happened while adding a new topic.' . $ex->getMessage(),
                        'code' => 59
                    ]
                ],500);
            }
        }
        else {

            return Response::json([
                'response' => [
                    'message' => 'Invalid request. Request should be in JSON.',
                    'code' => 51
                ]
            ],400);
        }

    }
```

Can you please let me know what the issue is?

Comment: You'd have to provide more data.

Comment: @majidarif , what kind ?

Comment: like more code in the function you are executing. There seems to be nothing wrong with the code you posted. Must be somewhere else.

Comment: I dont mind showing the code but like i said earlier the error is happening only when the conditions are met i.e. I am inside the if loop and I am returning JSON response it is only then I am getting this error.

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo, I know that will work but I would like to send 400 as well. otherwise I will get a 200 , with the status that is contradicting that .

Comment: the response message says that the timespan has expired and a status code of 200 is contradicting.

Comment: Can you add the route rule and the complete controller action?

Comment: @Artsemis: i am not saying i cant post it , but like i said earlier the error is happening only when the conditions are met i.e. I am inside the if loop and I am returning JSON response it is only then I am getting this error. There is too much company code that is happening in the controller action.

Comment: Well, could you atleast include a stacktrace?

Comment: @Gagan: Then paste the route. I completely understand what you're saying and the rest of the action and the route rules still very much matter.

Comment: @Artsemis done that ..